# pull command error : Failed connect to github.com:8080

Tags: git-pull

I tried to pull repository so that I can merge the changes made to my repository.
But while using the pull command it gives following error:

```
$ git pull https://github.com/ShrutiRuparel/depot.git master
error: Failed connect to github.com:8080; 
No error while accessing https://github.com/ShrutiRuparel/depot.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I tried setting the http proxy but no change.
`push` command worked perfectly fine but error with `pull` command.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The answer from basgys helped me and I also had to do this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed

Comment: Having same issue with bitbucket at the moment, 2 days ago everything was working fine, didn't touch anything, and now VPS rejects connecting to bitbucket, locally connection is fine, remote settings are same for both VPS and local and are correct, VPS has no http(s)_proxy records so --unset didn't help any bit, have no idea what this might be and what to do next.

Answer (score 46):

I had the same issue because I forgot to remove my proxy configuration on Git.

```
git config --global http.proxy
```

If it returns something you have to unset the value with the following command :

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

There is a lot of way to set a proxy for git and maybe this is not the good one. You can also check your environment variable.

```
echo $http_proxy
```

After that, it should works

Comment: You may also need to remove the https.proxy value as well.

Comment: To unset global config, use this command `git config --global --unset http.proxy`

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using https?

For private repo on GitHub, you would use (as [shown here](https://github.com/blog/642-smart-http-support)):

```
git clone https://username@github.com/username/project.git
```

But for a public repo, a simple:

```
git clone http://github.com/username/project.git
```

should be enough.

Comment: some tutorials (like three20) also show git://github.com.  Which doesnt seem to work, but changing it to https did