# error: Failed connect to github.com:8080; Connection refused

Tags: git, git-clone

I know this issue is not new, I kept looking for the answer but until now nothing worked for me.

The issue is that each time I try a `git clone` or `git pull` command, I receive the following error:

```
error: Failed connect to github.com:8080; Connection refused while accessing https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

(Here its https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack but it is just an example, I have this issue whith all URLs)

Comment: Port 8080 is not typically associated with https:// urls. 8443 is what I'd expect to see here, if it HAD to be something other than 443.

Comment: Try `git://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git`?

Comment: Actually I tried "git clone git://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git" and it worked whereas "git clone https: //github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack" keeps returning the same error...Any idea where does the issue could come from?

Comment: Well, `git clone https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git` is the correct command.  `git clone https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack` is simply not the correct syntax.  I would have expected a better error message, but I wouldn't have expected it to clone the repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if you've got git `http.proxy` or `https.proxy` configuration set, and unset both. See [pull command error : Failed connect to github.com:8080](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102361/pull-command-error-failed-connect-to-github-com8080)

Comment: I have already tried that. It is weird because even if I follow the process (unset both http & https), it keeps returning me an http.proxy setting (kuzh.polytechnique.fr:8080) and no https.proxy (which should be the right thing, no?)

Comment: Thanks! I forgot I recently configured git to work through a proxy. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try to set public/private rsa key pair before push or pull.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "youremailid@xxxx.com"
```

[image]