# Failed to connect to github.com:8080

Tags: git, github

I created a new Git repository but am unable to push it using terminal.

This is what I'm doing

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/dilipptt/first_app.git
git push origin master
```

and what I'm getting back:

> error: Failed to connect to `github.com:8080`; Connection refused while accessing `https://github.com/dilipptt/first_app.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack`
>   fatal: HTTP request failed

Comment: Show output of `git remote show origin`

Comment: @EmilDavtyan dilip@linuxmint /media/dilip/New Volume1/rails_projects/first_app $ git remote show origin
`error: Failed connect to github.com:8080; Connection refused while accessing https://git@github.com:dilipptt/first_app.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed`

Comment: Why is it trying to connect to port 8080? Do you have something in your `$HOME/.gitrc` that is messing with the port number?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512202/github-https-access

Comment: Perhaps you're using a proxy and need to unset `https_proxy`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6080561/694469

Answer (score 0):

With the changes you have made, the GitHub URL you have configured is wrong. You should either use the HTTP url as in `https://github.com/foo/bar.git` or the SSH url as in `git@github.com:foo/bar.git`

When you added the origin for the second time, you specified `git://git@github.com/dilipptt/first_app.git`

Instead you should specify

```
git remote add origin git@github.com/dilipptt/first_app.git
```

Please copy and paste text from the error instead of posting screenshots. The latter is hard for people who want to help you.

Comment: Can you post the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: `origin https://git@github.com:dilipptt/first_app.git (fetch)
origin https://git@github.com:dilipptt/first_app.git (push)`

Comment: Do the following:

1. `git remote rm origin`
2. `git remote add origin git@github.com:dilipptt/first_app.git`

Notice how there is no `https://` in the second line.

Cheers