# git fetch results in error

Tags: windows, git

In my work/office enviroment we use a proxy server. When working from home there is no proxy. I am trying to do a git fetch:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myapp/myrepo.git/': Fail
ed connect to github.com:8080; No error
```

Normally when I am in the office and I run this command it will ask for a password to the repo. At home it does not ask it instead it shows the error above.
How can I fix this/avoid this error?

Comment: try to remove proxy settings from git, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6080561/4709403)

Comment: I tried this but still the same error

Comment: I went through all my config settings and there is no proxy set

Comment: do you have a http proxy ?

Comment: no proxy working from home now

Comment: try to stop antivirus and firewalls and try again

Answer (score 0):

Even though you went through all your config settings, it is always safe to double-check:

```
git config --local  --unset http.proxy
git config --local  --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Check also your environment variables (for any `HTTP(S)_PROXY` variable)