# Connection error with cocoapods. Proxy CONNECT aborted

Tags: github, proxy, cocoapods

I have problem with instalation cococapods. I have done following steps in terminal:

~sudo gem update --system

~sudo gem install cocoapods

and after

~pod setup

I have this error message

```
MacBook-Pro-Aleksandr:~ aleksandrkarpov$ pod setup
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --depth=1

Cloning into 'master'...

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/': Proxy CONNECT aborted
```

I worked before with cocoapods and it was ok. In this case I don't know what to do. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: If you don't know the solution, can you advice in which direction I should go with this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102361/pull-command-error-failed-connect-to-github-com8080).

I wrote only in terminal:

```
git config --global http.proxy
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

and it resolved my problem.