# Error while doing pod set up

Tags: ios, rubygems, cocoapods

```
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
  $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --progress
  Cloning into 'master'...
  fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/': Failed to connect to 10.31.0.897 port 8888: Connection refused
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --progress

Cloning into 'master'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/': Failed to connect to 10.31.0.897 port 8888 : Connection refused
```

i installed cocoapods-1.2.0 successfully but I am getting the above error while doing the pod setup command ,even i tried with the different network same proxy issue its coming,someone help me out guys.

Edit:

i found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102361/pull-command-error-failed-connect-to-github-com8080)

Comment: you can access "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/" from your computer brower?

Comment: @Nhat Dinh i'm unable to access that , but i found the solution. Thanks for  response.