# Using .PAC proxy configuration file with Git

Tags: proxy, clone, git-bash

I tried to clone a repo from Git within my corporate network and i got the below message in git bash terminal.

"**$ git clone https://github.com/planetoftheweb/angulardata.git
Cloning into 'angulardata'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/planetoftheweb/angulardata.git/': Fa
iled connect to github.com:1080; No error**"

When I checked my internet LAN settings, I could see that we use a .pac configuration file in the format "**http://xxx.abcdefg.net/xyz-pqrst.com/xyz.pac**".

Can anyone help me to setup this kind of proxy in git bash terminal?

I refered other questions regarding this matter and couldn't find one which helps me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102361/pull-command-error-failed-connect-to-github-com8080

Comment: The ip and port of the proxy are usually written in the PAC file; configure those in git to make it work